# firefox tracking protection breaks facebook login

Tags: facebook, firefox, privacy

I am using simple facebook login from the cookbook in my web application. If firefox have the privacy.trackingprotection.enabled setting set to true, then the following happens:

- the window with facebook login pops up
- if the user is not logged in to facebook, then it can login
- the process stops here

I get the control to the callback if I close the window, but the login is deemed unsuccessful.

Without tracking protection enabled, it is working (i.e. the process does not stop.

Are there any way to use facebook login in a "tracking protection safe" mode?

The important parts of my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<my app id>',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function FaceBook(pageScript) {
this.pageScript = pageScript;
this.doc = document;
this.loggedIn = false;
}


FaceBook.prototype.loginCallBack = function(response) {
    var self = this;
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        self.loggedIn = response;
        self.pageScript.login_with_facebook(response.authResponse.userID, response.authResponse.accessToken)
    } else {
        self.doc.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Facebook login is unsuccessful'
    } 
  }

FaceBook.prototype.fblogin = function() {
    var self = this;
    if (! self.loggedIn ) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            self.loginCallBack(response);
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Firefox tell you about what specifically it has blocked, which resources? And if that’s how tracking protection works, by blocking FB resources or there cookies – well, then that’s how it is. User who want to use Facebook will either have to add an exception to the block list(?), or disable the feature.

Comment: no message, and nothing relevant in the web console either. it just hangs.
You can try it at https://sso.edemokraciagep.org/static/login.html

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get more answers, did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't recall I could solve it.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291865/how-to-load-facebook-sdk-asynchronous? I think we have to "disable as little functionality as possible when in incognito mode". In this case, we might have to disable Facebook login.

Comment: There's a bug report against Firefox for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226498 ... although it's not moved anywhere, however it's not been closed either.

Comment: In the meantime I came to the conclusion that facebook IS tracking, so breaking it with tracking protection is actually OK. Should I make an answer out of this, or is it too non-technical?