# How to load facebook sdk asynchronous

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook

I am using the following code to share in facebook.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId                : "1549906631990069",
  status               : true, 
  cookie               : true, 
  xfbml                : true, 

  oauth: true,
  frictionlessRequests : true
});
};

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

After that I have one image on clicking that Image the facebook share popup is coming.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shareOnFacebook() {
    var $temp = $(".wpProQuiz_points").find("span");
                    var scored = $temp.eq(2).text();

  FB.ui(
  {
    method        : 'feed',
    display       : 'iframe',
    name          : 'I have Scored '+ scored + ' in edumongoose quiz.',
    link          : 'https://quiz.dev.edumongoose.com'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('OK! User has published on Facebook.');

    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

}

the work good in chrome and firefox normal window, But when I goes in private window it show in error :
The resource at "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.

what wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't your fault! The browser is checking all downloaded script files against a list of scripts known to send tracking information back to the server.  In incognito or in private mode, browsers tend to block these scripts for privacy reasons.

A bug report has been raised against Firefox at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226498

Comment: how can I disable this, means by javascript ?

Comment: @JohnD.Doucette Why do you want to? People often use incognito mode to prevent services like Facebook from tracking their activity. A more elegant solution would be to disable as little functionality as possible when in incognito mode, but display a suggestion to the user that they should stop browsing in private if they want to experience your full site as it should be.

Comment: this is intentional, and there should be no way to prevent this from happening. else, the whole concept of private modes would be pointless.

Comment: @Chris J Why the edit? That bug report doesn't seem relevant since my answer depicts this as intentional behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I success was using

```
    <script src=\"/js/jquery.min.js\" async></script>
```

then:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     var options = {
     type: "delay",   
     time:1000, //1 sec
     scripts: [
                    "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appI$
                    "http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"
                            ],
     success: function () {
         FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
     }
    };
    $.lazyscript(options);

   });
   </script>
```

You can seek for lazyscript on Google and download it.